# Difference between ldexp(1, x) and exp2(x)

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, std, cmath

It seems if the floating-point representation has radix 2 (i.e. `FLT_RADIX == 2`) both `std::ldexp(1, x)` and `std::exp2(x)` raise `2` to the given power `x`.

Does the standard define or mention any expected behavioral and/or performance difference between them? What is the practical experience over different compilers?

Comment: Cppreference says "On binary systems (where FLT_RADIX is 2), std::ldexp is equivalent to std::scalbn.". So, I think you were thinking of scalbn instead of ldexp?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb No I was thinking ldexp, tho it's good to know that std::scalbn is also equivalent to these. I think when FLT_RADIX is 2, std::scalbn is implemented in terms of std::ldexp, or versa.

Comment: `std::ldexp` and `std::scalbn` takes integral exponent while `std::exp2` takes floating point exponent.

Comment: @Holt Damn, you are right. I missed this. However maybe the integral overloads of `std::exp2`  are based on `std::ldexp` or `std::scalbn`.

Comment: @plasmacel According to encppreference (and the standard), the integral overloads simply cast to `double`, e.g. `std::exp2(3)` is equivalent to `std::exp2((double)3)`, so there is no fallback to `std::ldexp` or `std::scalbn`.

Comment: @Holt: That's "as if". I expect _every_ implementation of `exp2` to call `ldexp`; however when the exponent has a fractional part then this is handled separately. `exp2(1.5)==exp2(1)*exp2(0.5)`.

Comment: Note: exp2 is C++11 (not C++03)

Comment: @MSalters Both `exp2` and `ldexp` may fall backs to common functions, but this is not guarantee. `exp2` does not (at least directly) fall backs to `ldexp` because `ldexp` only accepts `int` as exponent, and conversion from, e.g. `long`, to `double`, will maintain more information than conversion from `long` to `int` (just try with value outside the range of `int`, `exp2` gives you `inf` while `ldexp` gives you something else).

Comment: At this point it is clear that `std::ldexp` (and `std::scalbn`) provides better or at least the same performance for integer exponents than `std::exp2`. If one of you would like to write an answer, then please do it. It could be useful information for others too.

Comment: @MSalters Some hardware platforms provide `exp2(float)` in hardware, and there you may find that `ldexp(float,int)` is implemented via `exp2(float)`.

Comment: @Holt: `exp2(x)` would call `ldexp(int(x)) * __exp2_reduced(frac(x))` - the implementation of many floating-point functions starts by reducing the range of inputs.

Comment: From cppreference: "Although std::scalbn and std::scalbln are specified to perform the operation efficiently, on many implementations they are less efficient than multiplication or division by a power of two using arithmetic operators.", and "On many implementations, std::ldexp is less efficient than multiplication or division by a power of two using arithmetic operators. " So maybe the best to use `1.0 / (1 << abs(x))` for negative integer exponents and `1 << x` for positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exp2(x)` and `ldexp(x,i)` perform two different operations. The former computes 2<sup>x</sup>, where `x` is a *floating-point* number, while the latter computes x*2<sup>i</sup>, where `i` is an *integer*. For integer values of `x`, `exp2(x)` and `ldexp(1,int(x))` would be equivalent, provided the conversion of `x` to integer doesn't overflow.

The question about the relative efficiency of these two functions doesn't have a clear-cut answer. It will depend on the capabilities of the hardware platform and the details of the library implementation. While conceptually, `ldexpf()` looks like simple manipulation of the exponent part of a floating-point operand, it is actually a bit more complicated than that, once one considers overflow and gradual underflow via denormals. The latter case involves the rounding of the significand (mantissa) part of the floating-point number.

As `ldexp()` is generally an infrequently used function, it is in my experience fairly common that less of an optimization effort is applied to it by math library writers than to other math functions.

On some platforms, `ldexp()`, or a faster (custom) version of it, will be used as a building block in the software implementation of `exp2()`. The following code provides an exemplary implementation of this approach for `float` arguments:

```
#include <cmath>

/* Compute exponential base 2. Maximum ulp error = 0.86770 */
float my_exp2f (float a)
{
    const float cvt = 12582912.0f; // 0x1.8p23
    const float large = 1.70141184e38f; // 0x1.0p127
    float f, r;
    int i;

    // exp2(a) = exp2(i + f); i = rint (a)
    r = (a + cvt) - cvt;
    f = a - r;
    i = (int)r;
    // approximate exp2(f) on interval [-0.5,+0.5]
    r =             1.53720379e-4f;  // 0x1.426000p-13f
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.33903872e-3f); // 0x1.5f055ep-10f
    r = fmaf (r, f, 9.61817801e-3f); // 0x1.3b2b20p-07f
    r = fmaf (r, f, 5.55036031e-2f); // 0x1.c6af7ep-05f
    r = fmaf (r, f, 2.40226522e-1f); // 0x1.ebfbe2p-03f
    r = fmaf (r, f, 6.93147182e-1f); // 0x1.62e430p-01f
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+00f
    // exp2(a) = 2**i * exp2(f);
    r = ldexpf (r, i);
    if (!(fabsf (a) < 150.0f)) {
        r = a + a; // handle NaNs
        if (a < 0.0f) r = 0.0f;
        if (a > 0.0f) r = large * large; // + INF
    }
    return r;
}
```

Most real-life implementations of `exp2()` do not invoke `ldexp()`, but a custom version, for example when fast bit-wise transfer between integer and floating-point data is supported, here represented by internal functions `__float_as_int()` and `__int_as_float()` that re-interpret an IEEE-754 `binary32` as an `int32` and vice versa:

```
/* For a in [0.5, 4), compute a * 2**i, -250 < i < 250 */
float fast_ldexpf (float a, int i)
{
    int ia = (i << 23) + __float_as_int (a); // scale by 2**i
    a = __int_as_float (ia);
    if ((unsigned int)(i + 125) > 250) { // |i| > 125
        i = (i ^ (125 << 23)) - i; // ((i < 0) ? -125 : 125) << 23
        a = __int_as_float (ia - i); // scale by 2**(+/-125)
        a = a * __int_as_float ((127 << 23) + i); // scale by 2**(+/-(i%125))
    }
    return a;
}
```

On other platforms, the hardware provides a single-precision version of `exp2()` as a fast hardware instruction. Internal to the processor these are typically implemented by a table lookup with linear or quadratic interpolation. On such hardware platforms, `ldexp(float)` may be implemented in terms of `exp2(float)`, for example:

```
float my_ldexpf (float x, int i)
{
    float r, fi, fh, fq, t;

    fi = (float)i;
    /* NaN, Inf, zero require argument pass-through per ISO standard */
    if (!(fabsf (x) <= 3.40282347e+38f) || (x == 0.0f) || (i == 0)) {
        r = x;
    } else if (abs (i) <= 126) {
        r = x * exp2f (fi);
    } else if (abs (i) <= 252) {
        fh = (float)(i / 2);
        r = x * exp2f (fh) * exp2f (fi - fh);
    } else {
        fq = (float)(i / 4);
        t = exp2f (fq);
        r = x * t * t * t * exp2f (fi - 3.0f * fq);
    }
    return r;
```

}

Lastly, there are platforms that basically provide both `exp2()` and `ldexp()` functionality in hardware, such as the x87 instructions `F2XM1` and `FSCALE` on x86 processors.